# how to set default screen resolution in Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, display, resolution, settings

OK, so I found the new screen resolution setting button, thank you, but now I need to know how do you make it stay.

Every single time I reboot it resets the resolution back to some strange default that is not native to my monitor.

Also, the most annoying part is when I toggle the screen with my kvm to use on my other computer then when I flip it back the screen has been reset back to that same strange default setting.

So how can I change the screen resolution and make it be the default setting whenever I reboot or toggle my kvm?

I have a AMD A10 5800K with HD6670 Graphics, dual screen, one is a 1900x1080, my main monitor which keeps getting reset to 1400x1050

Thanks.